# Maven: Reverse-POM from Source

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, reverse

Suppose I have a fat-jar including all dependencies, probably built with *maven-assembly-plugin*. Is there some clever way to "reverse" the status-quo without having the original POM?

For example automagically generate a

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

just by having a package *com.fasterxml.jackson.core* inside my src folder

Comment: Open jar archive and check META-INF\maven\ directory there should be stored original pom.